# Daily Deal Sites Aggregators

Tags: aggregate

Recently I came across few sites (for eg. http://dealery.com) which provide One-Stop shopping for group buying coupons. I am wondering how these sites get deal info from various daily deal sites. I am sure they are not using any APIs. Because not all daily deal sites are providing APIs.

Are they doing screen scraping? OR are they using the RSS feeds to build their own database? 
If anyone know the solution for this, please share. I would greatly appreciate that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little bit old but thought I'd take the time to answer your question here. As Logan pointed out, deal aggregation scripts like the one Agriya has developed scrapes the data from daily deal websites in three ways:

1. It parses the data out of the RSS feed where available
2. It parses the data out of an XML feed provided by an affiliate network like Commission Junction
3. It uses regular expressions to parse the required data out of the HTML pages of the deal websites

Options 1 and 2 are fairly easy to achieve but option 3 requires you to be pretty good at formatting regular expressions. You've also got the added headache that if the deal site makes the slightest of changes to their HTML code then the regular expression needs to be redone.

Answer (score 0):

We run Australia's largest deal aggregator. We use the following methods to get our data;

- Parse data from sites XML feed (preferred)
- Parse data from sites RSS feed
- Custom screen scraping

As Peter mentioned the screen scraping can be a bit of a pain when sites change their code, however this doesn't happen that often. Maybe have to update 1 or 2 sites a month out of the 100 or so we list.

Answer (score 0):

Dealery might use RSS feeds or APIs because the sites I've seen aggregated by them actually offer RSS feeds and APIs.

Other sites:

- http://www.dodtracker.com
- http://www.todaysdod.com
- http://www.trackdailydeal.com

might do screen scraping because I can't find RSS feeds or APIs for some of the sites they aggregate from.